# Spanner SELECT statement as json array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to run a select statement in spanner which returns multiple rows and put that result into json format.

Here is the code:

```
def fetchmessages(self, pushid):
            rc = ResultCode.SUCCESS
            messages = ""

            def selectmessages(transaction):
                    messages = transaction.execute_update(
                    "SELECT Message.message_text FROM Message LEFT JOIN MessageStatus "
                    "ON (Message.message_id = MessageStatus.message_id) WHERE "
                    "MessageStatus.push_id = @id",
                    params={'id' : (pushid)},
                    param_types={'id' : param_types.STRING}
            )

            try:
                    self.client.run_in_transaction(selectmessages)
            except Exception as fetchexception:
                    rc = ResultCode.ERR_NO_MSG_FOUND
                    self.logger.debug(fetchexception)
                    pass

            if ResultCode.SUCCESS:
                    output = "{ 'pushid':'" + pushid + "', 'messages':" + messages + ", 'resultcode':" + str(rc.value) + "}"

            return output
```

The calling function just runs the output through jsonify and prints it out. The above code prints out:

```
"{ 'pushid':'cdd92f4ce847efa5c7f', 'messages':, 'resultcode':1}"
```

I want it to print out something like this:

```
"{ 'pushid':'cdd92f4ce847efa5c7f', 'Messages': [{'message': 'foo bar'}, { 'message': 'core dump'}], 'resultcode': 1}"
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's an issue in your `JOIN` statement:

   - each `push_id` contains several `message_id`, so both tables should be joined on `push_id`, not `message_id`
2. Potential relationship problem between tables `Message` and `MessageStatus`:

   - `push_id` should be the primary key of `MessageStatus`, and `MessageStatus` the parent of `Message`, check if DDL is correctly set with this example:

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE MessageStatus (
push_id string(50) NOT NULL
) PRIMARY KEY (push_id);


CREATE TABLE Message (
push_id string(50), NOT NULL,
message_id string(50) NOT NULL,
message_text string(50)
) PRIMARY KEY (push_id, message_id),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT MessageStatus ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Query script:

```
from google.cloud import spanner

def fetch_messages(instance_id, database_id):
    spanner_client = spanner.Client()
    instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)
    database = instance.database(database_id)

    with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
        results = snapshot.execute_sql(
            'SELECT Message.push_id, Message.message_id, Message.message_text FROM Message LEFT JOIN MessageStatus '
            'ON MessageStatus.push_id = Message.push_id WHERE MessageStatus.push_id="JDHK65FTRD832KJ"')
        for row in results:
            print(u'push_id: {}, message_id: {}, message_text: {}'.format(*row))


fetch_messages([INSTANCE_ID], [DATABASE_ID])
```

Result:

```
push_id: JDHK65FTRD832KJ, message_id: 1, message_text: First
push_id: JDHK65FTRD832KJ, message_id: 2, message_text: Second
push_id: JDHK65FTRD832KJ, message_id: 3, message_text: Third
```

Resources on GCP:

- [Schema and data model](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#creating-interleaved-tables)
- [Getting started with Cloud Spanner in Python](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/python/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your transaction is only a select statement. I recommend using the execute_sql method like shown:

```
spanner_client = spanner.Client()
instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)
database = instance.database(database_id)

with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
    results = snapshot.execute_sql(
        "SELECT Message.message_text FROM Message LEFT JOIN MessageStatus "
        "ON (Message.message_id = MessageStatus.message_id) WHERE "
        "MessageStatus.push_id = @id",
        params={'id' : (pushid)},
        param_types={'id' : param_types.STRING})

    for row in results:
        print(u'Message: {}'.format(*row))
```